# PHP5 session file cleanup never finishes

Tags: ubuntu, php, apache-2.2, session

My Ubuntu 12.04 server comes with this cron job, which must be for
cleaning up PHP session files

```
find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +24 ! -execdir fuser -s {} ; -delete
```

In my folder there are currently ca 1110000 such files and the server
performance deteriorates because the clean up process never finishes. The server is virtual on a Xen platform.

Is there a more performant method available?

Comment: If you `ps auxwwf`, do you see a `lsof` subprocess, with state D or DN, below the stuck `find` process? I had this on my Ubuntu server too, recently. The only way I could find to fix those was to restart the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this problem by assuming that performance of my server is simply not fast enough.  The second approach was to identify any scripts that generate unnecessary sessions and there was one key culprit.